# Reverse Engineering Exported DLL Function

Tags: c++, function-hooking, dll-injection

I am trying to read the arguments sent to an external dll file "FlashToolLib.dll". My hook function is never triggered, I am guessing because I have the address wrong.  I have tried the address in both the dll, and the exe

**FUNCTION:**

```
 public FlashTool_Connect_BROM_ByName
.text:5F866580 FlashTool_Connect_BROM_ByName proc near
.text:5F866580
.text:5F866580 var_B4          = dword ptr -0B4h
.text:5F866580 var_B0          = dword ptr -0B0h
.text:5F866580 var_AC          = dword ptr -0ACh
.text:5F866580 var_A8          = dword ptr -0A8h
.text:5F866580 var_A4          = dword ptr -0A4h
.text:5F866580 var_A0          = dword ptr -0A0h
.text:5F866580 var_9C          = dword ptr -9Ch
.text:5F866580 var_98          = dword ptr -98h
.text:5F866580 var_94          = dword ptr -94h
.text:5F866580 var_84          = dword ptr -84h
.text:5F866580 var_80          = dword ptr -80h
.text:5F866580 var_7C          = dword ptr -7Ch
.text:5F866580 var_78          = dword ptr -78h
.text:5F866580 var_68          = dword ptr -68h
.text:5F866580 var_64          = dword ptr -64h
.text:5F866580 var_60          = dword ptr -60h
.text:5F866580 var_5C          = dword ptr -5Ch
.text:5F866580 var_4C          = dword ptr -4Ch
.text:5F866580 var_48          = dword ptr -48h
.text:5F866580 var_44          = dword ptr -44h
.text:5F866580 var_40          = dword ptr -40h
.text:5F866580 var_30          = dword ptr -30h
.text:5F866580 var_2C          = dword ptr -2Ch
.text:5F866580 var_28          = dword ptr -28h
.text:5F866580 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:5F866580 arg_0           = dword ptr  8
.text:5F866580 arg_4           = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:5F866580 arg_8           = dword ptr  10h
.text:5F866580 arg_C           = dword ptr  14h
.text:5F866580 arg_10          = dword ptr  18h
```

**MY C++ CODE:**

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <detours.h>
#include <Windows.h>


void hookedFunc(DWORD arg1, DWORD arg2, DWORD arg3, DWORD arg4, DWORD arg5) {


    //Msgbox - arg 1//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    WCHAR szTest[10]; // WCHAR is the same as wchar_t
                      // swprintf_s is the same as sprintf_s for wide characters
    swprintf_s(szTest, 10, L"%d", arg1); // use L"" prefix for wide chars
    MessageBox(NULL, szTest, L"TEST", MB_OK); // a messageboy example again L as prefix
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    std::cout << "original function: argument1 = " << arg1 << std::endl; //print argument
    std::cout << "original function: argument2 = " << arg2 << std::endl; //print argument
    std::cout << "original function: argument3 = " << arg3 << std::endl; //print argument
    std::cout << "original function: argument4 = " << arg4 << std::endl; //print argument
    std::cout << "original function: argument5 = " << arg5 << std::endl; //print argument

}



BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    HMODULE FlashToolLib = GetModuleHandleA("FlashToolLib.dll");
    LPVOID fConnect = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(FlashToolLib, "FlashTool_Connect_BROM_ByName");


    switch (dwReason)
    {


    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:


        MessageBox(NULL, L"We are in.", L"Injection Success.", MB_OK);
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourAttach((PVOID*)fConnect,(PVOID)hookedFunc);
        DetourTransactionCommit();

    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: avoid using absolute addresses like 4axxxxx unless you are 120℅ sure that the modules in question will always load at the same base address

Comment: What would the alternative be?

Comment: have you tried to detour any other function?  It might be that the one that you hooked was called before your DLL was loaded, and then never called again.

Comment: I couldn't find docs on the `DetourAttach` function but I *think* you're using it incorrectly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981225/how-to-use-detourattach-for-a-pointer-to-a-function-in-hex). Maybe try with `DetourAttach((PVOID*) &fConnect, (PVOID) hookedFunc)`?

Comment: Apart from that, have you tried checking what's at the function's offset with a memory viewer, right after hooking, to check if it was done properly? Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the function to check if it gets called at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched the local drive for an unknown binary that uses a dll
found `calc.exe from gnuwin32` it uses 2 dlls `calc2.dll` and `readline5.dll`

copied all 3 of them to a test directory

```
e:\GNUWIN32\bin>cp -v calc.exe calc2.dll readline5.dll e:\test\detours\.
`calc.exe' -> `e:\\test\\detours\\./calc.exe'
`calc2.dll' -> `e:\\test\\detours\\./calc2.dll'
`readline5.dll' -> `e:\\test\\detours\\./readline5.dll'
```

wrote a small idc script to dump an arbitrary function

```
e:\test\detours>cat temp.idc
#include <idc.idc>
static main(void)
{
  auto fp;
  fp = fopen("bla.lst","w");
  GenerateFile(OFILE_LST,fp,MinEA(),MaxEA(),0x0);
  fclose(fp);
  Exit(2);
}
```

executed idafree to make a lst file

```
idag.exe -B -Stemp.idc calc2.dll
```

found the RVA of an arbitrary Function

```
e:\test\detours>grep -i imagebase bla.lst
.text:68D41000 ; Imagebase   : 68D40000

e:\test\detours>grep -i export.*zcmp bla.lst
.text:68DC1440 ; Exported entry 791. zcmp
.text:68DC1E10 ; Exported entry 792. zcmpmod

e:\test\detours>set /a 0x68dc1440-0x68d40000
529472
```

made a simple poc using the rva

```
//compiled and linked with enterprise wdk using
//cl /LD /W4 /Ox /Zi /analyze /EHsc d2r.cpp /link /DEBUG /RELEASE %linklibs% /EXPORT:DFunc
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include\detours.h"
#pragma comment (lib , "lib\\detours.lib")
typedef void (__cdecl *SomeFunction)(int,int,int,int,int,int);
void  __cdecl DFunc(int i,int j,int k,int l,int m,int n);
SomeFunction Func2Detour = (SomeFunction)((DWORD)GetModuleHandle("calc2.dll") + 529472 );
void  __cdecl DFunc(int i,int j,int k,int l,int m,int n) {
  int x = 0;
  printf("Arg %2d = 0x%08x\t0x%08x\n" , x++,i,*(int*)i);
  printf("Arg %2d = 0x%08x\n" , x++, j);
  printf("Arg %2d = 0x%08x\n" , x++, k);
  printf("Arg %2d = 0x%08x\t0x%08x\n" , x++,l,*(int *)l);
  printf("Arg %2d = 0x%08x\n" , x++, m);
  printf("Arg %2d = 0x%08x\n" , x++, n);
  Func2Detour(i,j,k,l,m,n);
}
INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE,DWORD Reason,LPVOID) {
  if (Reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH ){
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)Func2Detour, DFunc);
    DetourTransactionCommit();
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

compiled and linked as commented in source above

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

d2r.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:d2r.dll
/dll
/implib:d2r.lib
/debug
/DEBUG
/RELEASE
user32.lib
kernel32.lib
dbghelp.lib
/EXPORT:DFunc
d2r.obj
   Creating library d2r.lib and object d2r.exp
```

injected the dll with **withdll.exe** from detours sample

```
e:\test\detours>e:\detour\bin.X86\withdll.exe /d:d2r.dll .\calc.exe
withdll.exe: Starting: `.\calc.exe'
withdll.exe:   with `e:\test\detours\d2r.dll'
C-style arbitrary precision calculator (version 2.11.10.1)
Calc is open software. For license details type:  help copyright
[Type "exit" to exit, or "help" for help.]

;
```

the detour dumps all the six arguments

```
; 2+2
Arg  0 = 0x0134b750     0x00000002
Arg  1 = 0x00000001
Arg  2 = 0x00000000
Arg  3 = 0x68de11f4     0x00000002
Arg  4 = 0x00000001
Arg  5 = 0x00000000
        4
; 45^89
        1367457148855142104017389933103900519105
058455901337287730364197964327832579556343262083
; 4^8
Arg  0 = 0x0134b7f8     0x00000004
Arg  1 = 0x00000001
Arg  2 = 0x00000000
Arg  3 = 0x68de11fc     0x00000004
Arg  4 = 0x00000001
Arg  5 = 0x00000000
        65536
; 4.5^8
Arg  0 = 0x0134b828     0x0000002d
Arg  1 = 0x00000001
Arg  2 = 0x00000000
Arg  3 = 0x0134dab8     0x0000000a
Arg  4 = 0x00000001
Arg  5 = 0x00000000
        168151.25390625
; 3&5
Arg  0 = 0x0134b828     0x00000003
Arg  1 = 0x00000001
Arg  2 = 0x00000000
Arg  3 = 0x68de11f8     0x00000003
Arg  4 = 0x00000001
Arg  5 = 0x00000000
        1
```